# 3 phase AC circuit problem

Tags: ac, inductor

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am confused with problem 12.3. I have attached the solution and my attempt. I am confused why we are getting factor of 2, can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Not my field of study. But I wonder why you multiplied VI* by 3. The 3 voltages are not in phase. So how can you multiply by 3 to calculate instantaneous power ?

Comment: I did for phase a and for phase b, voltage & current both will lag by 120 and similarly for phase c, they will lead by 120 and will give the same result as phase a. So, the calculation for b & c phase is not required.

Comment: Yea magnitude of their products are the same in all phases. But while summing, you didn't take into consideration of phase difference between those products. For example you can't write : 5 sinwt + 5 sin (wt-45) = 10 sin wt ...you did something like this .

Comment: @MITURAJ, no that part is okay. Problem was that I showed the answer in terms of Vrms and Irms whereas I should have done that in terms of peak values which would give a factor of 2 as user287001 explained.

Comment: Yea because RMS value doesn't look into the phase of the quantity. But if you had calculated the sum of instantaneous phase powers , including its phasors,  you can see that sin and cos terms will compute to a constant.

Comment: In the original solution, that's why they are adding every power separately instead of multiplying by 3. Phase angles of each phase power are different even though magnitudes are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You calculated the average transferred power. You have calculated it right. You use RMS value phasors, the book uses peak values. That explains the factor 2.
2. The book wanted the instantneous power to the load. There's a proof that in every moment the total power is the same. Your calculation gives no info about how power transfer varies during one AC voltage cycle. Your calculation is NOT a proof for the fact that the total power transfer is constant (=the same in every moment).

Comment: please take a look https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349472/ordinary-differential-relay-problem