# Uncontrolled Bridge Rectifier

Tags: power, power-electronics, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

[image]

[image]

I am getting wrong answer for the above problem. My book says R should be 23ohms. Please guide me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: 230V is already in RMS, passing through the bridge still 230V... so 230V/10A = 23 ohms

Comment: If you replace the current source with a resistive load then the current and the voltage have the same waveform (V = I . R). Thus the peak value of the current will be \$10 \sqrt2\$. So \$R=V_{pk}/I_{pk}=230 \sqrt2 / 10 \sqrt2 = 23 \Omega.\$

Comment: 230V * sqrt(2) is the peak voltage, but you need Current in RMS

Comment: Sir, what is wrong in my solution ? Shouldn't the Pavg be Irms^2R ?

Comment: You supposed that the current is pure DC (from what I've seen in your solution) so the mean (avg) value is the same as RMS. But it's not. It's avg value will be less then its RMS value.

Comment: I missed the same waveform thing. Thanks @RohatKılıç.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, please take a look https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349472/ordinary-differential-relay-problem

Comment: @RohatKılıç please help me with this problem https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350657/full-bridge-vsi-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

230V is already in RMS, passing through the bridge still 230V... so 230V/10A = 23 ohms – Dr Yunke Jan 16 at 8:48